# Bootstrap 4 navbar-toggler-icon does not appear

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Visit: https://jsfiddle.net/8tpm4z00/

```
<div class="container">

  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavigation" aria-controls="myNavigation" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">KP</a>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavigation">
      <div class="navbar-nav">
        <a class="p-3 nav-item nav-link active " href="#">Home</a>
        <a class="p-3 nav-item nav-link " href="#">About</a>
        <a class="p-3 nav-item nav-link " href="#">Contact Me</a>
      </div><!-- <div class="navbar-nav"> -->
  </div><!-- <div class="collapse navbar-collapse"> -->

</div><!-- <div class="container"> -->
```

The `.navbar-toggler-icon` does not appear on the navbar-toggler button when the menu is collapsed for mobile responsiveness.

I have searched about this problem and adjusted the jquery and bootstrap links also. By putting the jquery link above the bootstrap 4 links. But that does not seem to work. The external libraries are linked in my HTML in the same order as the jsfiddle.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Update:**

`navbar-inverse` is no longer available in B4 version, you can use `navbar-dark` instead.

---

Use `navbar-inverse bg-inverse` instead of `.navbar-default`

```
<section role="navigation">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse bg-inverse navbar-toggleable-sm fixed-top"><!-- navbar-inverse -->

    <div class="container">

      <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavigation" aria-controls="myNavigation" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">KP</a>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavigation">
          <div class="navbar-nav">
            <a class="p-3 nav-item nav-link active " href="#">Home</a>
            <a class="p-3 nav-item nav-link " href="#">About</a>
            <a class="p-3 nav-item nav-link " href="#">Contact Me</a>
          </div><!-- <div class="navbar-nav"> -->
      </div><!-- <div class="collapse navbar-collapse"> -->

    </div><!-- <div class="container"> -->

  </nav>
</section>
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8tpm4z00/6/)

Comment: How do you get it to show if you don't want a dark navbar?

Answer (score 15):

### If you use bootstrap 4 beta:

You can only add the **navbar-dark** classe in the *nav* tag.

Result:

```
<nav class = "navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark fixed-top navbar-default" role = "navigation">
     <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
         <img class = "img-responsive logo" src = "~/Content/Images/ogo__160x36.png" alt = "" />
     </a>
     <button type = "button" class = "navbar-toggler" data-toggle = "collapse" data-target = "#menuPrincipal" aria-controls = "navbarNav" aria-expanded = "false" aria-label = "Toggle navigation ">
         <span class = "navbar-toggler-icon"> </ span>
     </button>
     <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" ...>...</div>
</nav>
```

Comment: thanks for this, was having the damnedest time figuring out why this wasn't working now that version 4 is stable

Comment: You also have to use bg-dark and there is no navbar-default.

Answer (score 6):

if you don't use navbar-light or dark set background-img some image into .navbar-toggler-icon as follow

```
.navbar-toggler-icon {
background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg viewBox='0 0 30 30' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000…p='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' d='M47h22M4 15h22M423h22'/%3e%3c/svg%3e);
}
```

or use fa-bars from font awsome

Comment: this was my issue, although the code posted seems broken. maybe a single quote missing.

Comment: .navbar-toggler-icon {
 background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 32 32' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cpath stroke='rgba(92,46,78, 1)' stroke-width='2' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' d='M4 8h24M4 16h24M4 24h24'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}
Change stroke='rgba to something that fits your solution ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Use **navbar-dark** instead for **navbar-inverse** and bg-dark also instead of bg-inverse

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-dark navbar-expand-md bg-dark ">
```

Answer (score 1):

I have replaced `class="navbar-toggler"` with `class="btn"`.

The code looks like this:

```
<!--Toggler-->
<button class="btn" type="button" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" data-bs-target="#offcanvasNavbar" aria-controls="offcanvasNavbar" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
```

It works.

Comment: A description of why this works would be useful. :)